# bitcoin-qt crashes when any bitcoin.conf file is used

Tags: mac, bitcoin.conf

I am running 0.8.5 beta on my mac under 10.8.3 and it runs fine until I try to use a bitcoin.conf file.

If there is a file, even if it is completely empty it will crash before the application even starts.  All I receive is a message "Bitcoin-Qt quit unexpectedly."  The is no log even generated.

I have tried redownloading the application and trashing all the files including the blockchain.

If I remove the bitcoin.conf file the application launches and runs fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.